# REST Request - AWS Access Key ID and AWS Secret Access Key

Tags: rest-api, rest, aws, amazon-s3

I am reading this document [Authenticating Rest Requests](https://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html)

The first paragraph says ..

> Every non-anonymous request to S3 must contain authentication information to establish the identity of the principal making the request. In REST, this is done by first putting the headers in a canonical format, then signing the headers using your **AWS Secret Access Key**.
>
> There are two ways to send your signature with a request. The first is to put your **AWS Access Key ID** and the **signature you computed** into the Authorization header.

My 1st question is-

Is AWS Secret Access Key the same as AWS Access Key ID?
if not the same, Where do I get the AWS Secret Access Key and AWS Access Key ID?

My 2nd question is about '**signature you computed**'

I understand that this signature is computed like this -

```
String signatureYouComputed = base64(hmac-sha1(VERB + "\n" 
                                 + CONTENT-MD5 + "\n" 
                                 + CONTENT-TYPE + "\n" 
                                 + DATE + "\n" 
                                 + CanonicalizedAmzHeaders + "\n" 
                                 + CanonicalizedResource))
```

Here how do i get CONTENT-MD5, CanonicalizedAmzHeaders, and CanonicalizedResource?

I know these are basic questions for experienced integration developers but not for everyone. Please help me understand.

Comment: Right now, it looks like the assistance you need is specific to the AWS platform, not to the Salesforce platform. If that is *not* the case, could you please make an [edit] to clarify? Questions about AWS are not on topic here but would likely be on StackOverflow.

Comment: This is for Salesforce. I am trying to Send a Request to an External System. This external system uses the same structure as AWS to autheticate  requests from Salesforce. When I make a call to the external web service from salesforce, i need to send a signature with the request like this..  "Authorization: SFDC " + AccessKeyId + ":"  + base64(hmac-sha1(VERB + "\n" 
            + CONTENT-MD5 + "\n" 
            + CONTENT-TYPE + "\n" 
            + DATE + "\n" 
            + CanonicalizedHeaders + "\n" 
            + CanonicalizedResource))

Comment: I recommend you go through the [Apex Integration Services Module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services) on Trailhead where authentication during REST calls is covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is both an AWS and SF question, but I think I can help. You're trying to Authenticate via HMAC. It depends on the SHA1 Algo and the  Content-MD5 header that is later base64 encoded.

1. **Re: Keys/ Secrets**: In AWS, Access keys consist of two parts: an access key ID (for example, AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE) and a secret access key (for example, wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY). [**This link**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-sec-cred-types.html#access-keys-and-secret-access-keys) will give you the docs on how to get both of them.
2. RE: **Computing the Signature**: This code is pretty much what I use:

```
@future (callout=true)
public static void sendRequest(String jsonString){
    DateTime dtNow= System.Now();
    String dateFormat= dtNow.format('E, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss z','GMT'); // date format as per the timezone of org
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(System.Label.EndPoint); // endpoint URL

    String strMd5= EncodingUtil.base64Encode (Crypto.generateDigest('MD5', Blob.valueOf(jsonString)));
    String strCanonical = 'application/json' + ',' + strMd5 + ',' + request URL + ',' +dateFormat;
    String strSignature = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(generateHmacSHA1Signature(strCanonical, system.label.Secret_Key));
    String authorizationHeader = system.label.APIAuth + ' ' + System.Label.Access_Id + ':' + strSignature;req.setMethod('POST');

    req.setHeader('ACCEPT',System.label.Accept_Header); // accept headers
    req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader); 
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', System.label.Content_Type); // content Type 
    req.setHeader('DATE',dateFormat);
    req.setHeader('CONTENT_MD5',strMd5);
    req.setHeader('request_uri',System.Label.EndPoint);
    req.setBody(jsonString);
    Http http = new Http();

    if(!test.isRunningTest()){
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    }
}

public static blob generateHmacSHA1Signature(String canonical_str, String secreteKey){ 
    Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMacSHA1', blob.valueof(canonical_str),blob.valueof(secreteKey)); 
    return mac;
}
```

I got it from this blog, and they gives some more info https://www.thinqloud.com/hmac-authentication-in-salesforce/

Comment: Thank you @ohana. I had seen the thinqloud article. It cleared some of my queries. In my use case, to be able to succesfully authenticate my request i have to follow the steps mentioned here https://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html. I got lost along the way with CananicalizedHeaders and CanonicalizedResource. How do I create those ? What is the difference between Headers - i.e (content-md5, content-type, date, and anything that starts with x-amz) and CananicalizedHeaders ?

Comment: @user4947 the CanonicalizedAmzHeaders  apply only headers that start with 'x-amz-' . At this point, I don't think you have to worry about it.  The CanonicalizedResource is the URL for your resource on s3 that you're trying to access.  This tells you how to build the url: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html I think if you post these questions separately, you can get a more detailed response.

Comment: thank you for the documen for the suggestion of posting questions separately. I will do as suggested.

Comment: AWS v4 signature is supported out of the box in Summer '19 (going live in mid-June 2019) via NamedCredentials:  https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer19/release-notes/rn_security_more_auth_protocols.htm